# How to manually process XSL transformation in Android 2.x

Tags: android, xslt

I'm aware that [Android 2.x doesn't support XSL transformations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3840207/is-the-android-browser-capable-of-performing-an-xsl-transform) and that [it's a known bug](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=9312), but I can't seem to work out how to implement this functionality any other way.  I've looked at [3rd party libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4078479/what-android-3rd-party-libraries-are-there) but there don't seem to be any which help fill this gap.

I've got various files I need to parse, all work find in Honeycomb - all are similar to the code below - is there any way this is possible on Android 2.x?

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="Weather.xsl"?>

<!DOCTYPE rssfeed[
<!ENTITY feedData SYSTEM "http://webservice.weatherzone.com.au/rss/wx.php?lt=aploc&lc=12493&obs=1&fc=1&warn=1">
]>

<feed>
    <title>weather</title>
&feedData;
</feed>
```

XSL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

<xsl:template match="/">
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=320px, initial-scale=1.0" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="content">
            <br />
            <h1><xsl:value-of select="feed/title"/></h1>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="//item"/>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="item">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="title='weather'">
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <h2><xsl:value-of select="title"/></h2>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="title='weather forecast'">
                    <div class="forecast">
                        <xsl:value-of select="description" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
                    </div>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:value-of select="description" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: may be **[This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16318998/how-to-transform-xml-with-xslt-and-display-it-in-android-webview/19402040#19402040)** will help you.