# XML/XSL transform using Javascript/JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, xslt

Can anyone tell me if there is a way to do an XML/XSLT transformation on the client side using Javascript or JQuery, a way that works in all major browsers? (Chrome, Safari, Firefox and IE)? Thanks.

Comment: Maybe this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9847395/using-client-side-xslt-transformations-in-the-html5-era

Comment: or this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5722410/how-can-i-use-javascript-to-transform-xml-xslt

Answer (score 6):

I should state from the start that I wrote this script, but if you're looking to just do some transformations and pass some parameters to your XSLT (nothing too fancy) then you can try [Magic XML](http://tomdavies.azurewebsites.net/magicxml/).

You can also have it automatically pull in your data and apply transformations by setting some `data-` attributes on your DOM elements. For example...

```
<div data-xml="example.xml" data-xslt="transform.xslt"></div>
```

...would automatically pull in data from example.xml and apply the transform.xslt to it.

It works in Opera, Chrome, Firefox and IE and is open source.

Comment: The MagicXML URL seems to be non-responsive, and I believe it is hosted by you juddging from the domain name. I'm interested in the library.

Comment: Hey tzot, sorry about that! Updated the URL now, should be good to go.

Comment: Which version of XSLT do we end up with? Is it 1.0 or 2.0?

Comment: magic xml is just a wrapper around  "client side example"  found in w3c. It wont fix any upcoming problems.  I am wondering if I can reimplement the node-set function using wgx.

Answer (score 4):

Have you considered [Saxon CE](http://www.saxonica.com/ce/index.xml)?  It used to require a commercial licence for deployment but the latest version has been released as open source.

Comment: Coincidentally, the open source Saxon-CE 1.1 release was announced on the same day as this answer: [Saxon-CE 1.1](http://www.saxonica.com/ce/index.xml)

Comment: @pgfearo thanks for the heads up, I've edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: awesome! the doc is great too!

Answer (score 1):

There's [a client side example](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xsl_client.asp).

Comment: does not work when xsl stylesheet contains node-set in edgeHTML 14

Comment: @yanbellavance Yes, browsers have moved on a bit since that article was written

Comment: @MarkKCowan Missed your comment when you first posted it, but it only uses MSXML when it detects IE

Answer (score 0):

I've had reasonably good experiences with [Sarissa](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sarissa/).  The transformation interface supported by some XForms engines is also a convenient way to manage transformations in the client.