# Validating XML against Schematron in browsers

Tags: xml, internet-explorer, schematron

Internet browsers support validating XML against XSD, but do there exist any plugins that can augment these capabilities to include Schematron or RELAX NG? I'm looking for one that works with Internet Explorer.

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution is to take the XSL which can be generated from the Schematron schema for validation. Performing the XSL transformation is also possible in the web browser. Some solutions are described here: [xml-xsl-transform-using-javascript-jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14988645/xml-xsl-transform-using-javascript-jquery)

To generate the validation stylesheet from the Schematron schema you could use [XML ValidatorBuddy](http://www.xml-buddy.com/ValidatorBuddy.htm)

Answer (score 0):

all I know there is no one,only a few XML editor tools can support the validation against the schematron or RELAX NG