# IE9-11 SVG width is not 100% and jQuery Animation not working correctly

Tags: jquery, debugging, animation, svg, cross-browser

Animations Problem:

Chrome & Firefox works
IE9-11: Animations works not correctly :/

myArray contains the buildings ID and shuffle is only for randomize the sort

```
 var skyline = Snap.select("#skylines");
 var bottles = [
        "Flasche1",
        "Flasche2",
        "Flasche3",
        "Flasche4"
    ];

 $("#drink").click(function () {
        hideBuildings(allBuildings);
        startBuildings(bottles);
        $('.main').moveTo(3); //Onepage Scroll
    });


 function hideBuildings(myArray) {
        for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i = i + 1) {
            $('#' + myArray[i]).css({opacity: 0 });
            slideDown(myArray[i]);

        }
    }
/*
 * Slide Down
 */
function slideDown(el) {
    var cuel = skyline.select("#" + el);
//the height of a building
    var a = cuel.getBBox().height;
    cuel.animate({
        transform: "t0, t" + a
    }, 600);

}



function startBuildings(myArray) {
        var myArray = shuffleArray(myArray);
        for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i = i + 1) {
            $('#' + myArray[i]).css({opacity: 1});
            slideUp(myArray[i], 0, randomFromInterval(1470, 2000));
        }
    }

//Slide Up
function slideUp(el, y, duration) {
        var cuel = skyline.select("#" + el);
        cuel.animate({
            transform: "t0, t" + -y,
            opacity: 1

        }, duration, mina.bounce);


    }
```

SVG Problem:

SVG looks correct in Firefox and Chrome but not in IE11 i want 100% width but is not working in IE9-11

SVG Open tag:

```
<svg id="skylines"  version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="703px"
preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin"  height="123.365px" viewBox="0 0 703 123.365" enable-background="new 0 0 703 123.365" xml:space="preserve">
```

CSS:

```
.skyline-wrapper svg {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}
```

I can not accurately describe both problems because I have no idea where they come from

Link http://swisslayer.ch/drink/splash.html  click on "JA" 
thx 
greetings from Switzerland

Comment: try add this rule .skyline-wrapper{width:100%;} because I don't find styles for this element and change this .skyline-wrapper svg{height: auto;}

Comment: thx  but same result ;/

Comment: for a test create new empty html file and put only svg code plus this style: html,body,svg{width:100%; height:100%;} *{margin:0; padding:0;} and check this on IE

Comment: ohh this works http://swisslayer.ch/drink/svg.html

Comment: ok perfect so now try add another style and code from you first version. JS add at last ok first only html and css and check results

Comment: ok so add to this div this styles: .divsvg{display:block; width:100%; height:auto; max-height:600px;} and write me message, you can try use fix height example 400px.

Comment: I have now: <div style="position:fixed; bottom:0; width:100%; height:100%; z-index:-200;"><svg></div> result:http://swisslayer.ch/drink/svg.html 100% width in IE11

Comment: ah and here your example http://swisslayer.ch/drink/svg2.html

Comment: ok I used this style and look ok bottom: -150px;
    display: block;
    height: 332px;
    max-height: 600px;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
}
but bottom and height is not fixed you can write function in jquery to check how is current height svg element and add this height to div and set margin bottom.

Comment: I show you how you can do this for your example but give me a time.

Comment: hi i will check http://stickyjs.com/  this but i need to go very very thank your for help! I hope one day makes the IE like the others:D I'm back tomorrow because I write here if I did not it come out; D

Comment: i have tried but without success  
Link: http://swisslayer.ch/test2/  
`/* Sticky Footer
     ================================================== */
    setHeight('#footer');
    $(window).resize(function () {
        setHeight('#footer');
    });

    function setHeight(element) {

        //Height in IE need to 100% for fullwidth dont know why.. ?
        var currentHeight = $(element).height();
        $(element).css({ height: currentHeight  });
    } `

CSS:

Comment: try use this script: 
$(window).on("load resize",function(e){
    var height = $("#skylines").outerHeight(true);
    $("#footer").css("height", height);
});

Comment: Hi, nothing ;/ http://swisslayer.ch/test2/ on resize the #footer goes up and in IE shows only the Half svg  really do not know what I should do this **** IE

Comment: ok if this is not important I can help you in weekend ok, but I must contact with you.

Comment: im online in irc.freenode.net as "cannap" all day :D i try some other things thank you :D i will writte my experience

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cross-platform SVG rotation animation:](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21093244/cross-platform-svg-rotation-animation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference between the 100% cross-browser rendering is `xml:space`. Unfortunately:

> The xml:space attribute is not supported in SVG.

Use a beautifier or XSLTProcessor to normalize the whitespace.

**References**

- [MS-SVG:2.1.1 [SVG11] Section 5.10.2, The xml:lang and xml:space attributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg557993)
- [Using client side XSLT transformations in the HTML5 era](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9847395/using-client-side-xslt-transformations-in-the-html5-era/15531579#15531579)
- [Native XML object types and legacy websites](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh180177)