# XSLT transformation using browser

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, xslt, transformation

I need to transform xml data to html using xslt transformation. I have some predefined xslt files which work perfectly in IE10, but not in Chrome or Firefox. For firefox it doesn't work at all. For Chrome there are some xslt files which work fine for the same xml data, and there are others that doesn't work. I need to know whether there are any limitations/specification for xslt files to be cross browser xslt files. For example i have 2 xslt files
 1. the whole content is in `<xsl:template match='/'>` tag (works for Chrome)
 2. the whole content is in different tags, some of them are `<xsl:variable>` tags, the others `<xsl:template>` (doesn't work for Chrome)

Here is what i do

```js
    //Load xsl and xml files from their paths and make transformation
            loadXMLFile(xslPath, function (loadedXSL) {

                loadXMLFile(xmlPath, function (loadedXml) {
                    var output = transformXML(loadedXml, loadedXSL, null);

                }, function (errMsg) {
                    alert(errMsg);
                });
            }, function (errMsg) {
                alert(errMsg);
            });

//Function for loading local files
function loadXMLFile(path, doneFunction, errorFunction) {
    //for IE
    if (window.ActiveXObject) {
        $.ajax(path, {
            cache: true,
            crossDomain: true,
            dataType: 'text',
        }).done(function (data) {
            doneFunction(parseTextToXML(data));
        }).error(function (data) {
            alert(data.statusText + "-" + data.responseText);
        });
    }
    //For Firefox/Chrome
    else {
        $.ajax(path, {
            type: 'GET',
            contentType: 'text/xml',
            dataType: 'xml',
            mimeType: 'text/xml',
        }).done(function (data) {
            doneFunction(data);
        }).error(function (xhr) {
            errorFunction(xhr);
        });
    }
} 

//Function for transformation
function transformXML(xmlDoc, xslDoc, responseType) {
    var data;
    if (window.ActiveXObject || responseType == "msxml-document") {
        data = xmlDoc.transformNode(xslDoc);
    }
        // code for Chrome, Firefox, Opera, etc.
    else if (document.implementation && document.implementation.createDocument) {
        var xsltProcessor = new XSLTProcessor();
        xsltProcessor.importStylesheet(xslDoc);

        if (navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('firefox') > -1) {
            //Do Firefox-related activities
            data = xsltProcessor.transformToDocument(xmlDoc);
        }
        else {
            data = xsltProcessor.transformToFragment(xmlDoc, document);
        }
    }
    return data;
}
```

xsl file content

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes" ?>
<!--
 |
 | XSLT REC Compliant Version of IE5 Default Stylesheet
 |
 | Original version by Jonathan Marsh
 | http://msdn.microsoft.com/xml/samples/defaultss/defaultss.xsl
 |
 | Conversion to XSLT 1.0 REC Syntax by Steve Muench
 |
 -->
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <xsl:output indent="no" method="html"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <HTML>
      <HEAD>
        <SCRIPT>
          <xsl:comment>
            <![CDATA[
                  function f(e){
                     if (e.className=="ci") {
                       if (e.children(0).innerText.indexOf("\n")>0) fix(e,"cb");
                     }
                     if (e.className=="di") {
                       if (e.children(0).innerText.indexOf("\n")>0) fix(e,"db");
                     } e.id="";
                  }
                  function fix(e,cl){
                    e.className=cl;
                    e.style.display="block";
                    j=e.parentElement.children(0);
                    j.className="c";
                    k=j.children(0);
                    k.style.visibility="visible";
                    k.href="#";
                  }
                  function ch(e) {
                    mark=e.children(0).children(0);
                    if (mark.innerText=="+") {
                      mark.innerText="-";
                      for (var i=1;i<e.children.length;i++) {
                        e.children(i).style.display="block";
                      }
                    }
                    else if (mark.innerText=="-") {
                      mark.innerText="+";
                      for (var i=1;i<e.children.length;i++) {
                        e.children(i).style.display="none";
                      }
                    }
                  }
                  function ch2(e) {
                    mark=e.children(0).children(0);
                    contents=e.children(1);
                    if (mark.innerText=="+") {
                      mark.innerText="-";
                      if (contents.className=="db"||contents.className=="cb") {
                        contents.style.display="block";
                      }
                      else {
                        contents.style.display="inline";
                      }
                    }
                    else if (mark.innerText=="-") {
                      mark.innerText="+";
                      contents.style.display="none";
                    }
                  }
                  function cl() {
                    e=window.event.srcElement;
                    if (e.className!="c") {
                      e=e.parentElement;
                      if (e.className!="c") {
                        return;
                      }
                    }
                    e=e.parentElement;
                    if (e.className=="e") {
                      ch(e);
                    }
                    if (e.className=="k") {
                      ch2(e);
                    }
                  }
                  function ex(){}
                  function h(){window.status=" ";}
                  document.onclick=cl;
              ]]>
          </xsl:comment>
        </SCRIPT>
        <STYLE>
          BODY {font:x-small 'Verdana'; margin-right:1.5em}
          .c  {cursor:pointer}
          .b  {color:red; font-family:'Courier New'; font-weight:bold;
          text-decoration:none}
          .e  {margin-left:1em; text-indent:-1em; margin-right:1em}
          .k  {margin-left:1em; text-indent:-1em; margin-right:1em}
          .t  {color:#990000}
          .xt {color:#990099}
          .ns {color:red}
          .dt {color:green}
          .m  {color:blue}
          .tx {font-weight:bold}
          .db {text-indent:0px; margin-left:1em; margin-top:0px;
          margin-bottom:0px;padding-left:.3em;
          border-left:1px solid #CCCCCC; font:small Courier}
          .di {font:small Courier}
          .d  {color:blue}
          .pi {color:blue}
          .cb {text-indent:0px; margin-left:1em; margin-top:0px;
          margin-bottom:0px;padding-left:.3em; font:small Courier;
          color:#888888}
          .ci {font:small Courier; color:#888888}
          PRE {margin:0px; display:inline}
        </STYLE>
      </HEAD>
      <BODY class="st">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </BODY>
    </HTML>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="processing-instruction()">
    <DIV class="e">
      <SPAN class="b">
        <xsl:call-template name="entity-ref">
          <xsl:with-param name="name">nbsp</xsl:with-param>
        </xsl:call-template>
      </SPAN>
      <SPAN class="m">
        <xsl:text>&lt;?</xsl:text>
      </SPAN>
      <SPAN class="pi">
        <xsl:value-of select="name(.)"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        &#160;
      </SPAN>
      <SPAN class="m">
        <xsl:text>?></xsl:text>
      </SPAN>
    </DIV>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="processing-instruction('xml')">
    <DIV class="e">
      <SPAN class="b">
        <xsl:call-template name="entity-ref">
          <xsl:with-param name="name">nbsp</xsl:with-param>
        </xsl:call-template>
      </SPAN>
      <SPAN class="m">
        <xsl:text>&lt;?</xsl:text>
      </SPAN>
      <SPAN class="pi">
        <xsl:text>xml </xsl:text>
        <xsl:for-each select="@*">
          <xsl:value-of select="name(.)"/>
          <xsl:text>="</xsl:text>
          <xsl:value-of select="."/>
          <xsl:text>"&#160;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </SPAN>
      <SPAN class="m">
        <xsl:text>?></xsl:text>
      </SPAN>
    </DIV>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@*">
    <SPAN>
      <xsl:attribute name="class">
        <xsl:if test="xsl:*/@*">
          <xsl:text>x</xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:text>t</xsl:text>
      </xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:value-of select="name(.)"/>
    </SPAN>
    <SPAN class="m">="</SPAN>
    <B>
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </B>
    <SPAN class="m">"&#160;</SPAN>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="text()">
    <DIV class="e">
      <SPAN class="b"> </SPAN>
      <SPAN class="tx">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      </SPAN>
    </DIV>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="comment()">
    <DIV class="k">
      <SPAN>
        <A STYLE="visibility:hidden" class="b" onclick="return false" 
           onfocus="h()">-</A>
        <SPAN class="m">
          <xsl:text>&lt;!--</xsl:text>
        </SPAN>
      </SPAN>
      <SPAN class="ci" id="clean">
        <PRE>
          <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </PRE>
      </SPAN>
      <SPAN class="b">
        <xsl:call-template name="entity-ref">
          <xsl:with-param name="name">nbsp</xsl:with-param>
        </xsl:call-template>
      </SPAN>
      <SPAN class="m">
        <xsl:text>--></xsl:text>
      </SPAN>
      <SCRIPT>f(clean);</SCRIPT>
    </DIV>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*">
    <DIV class="e">
      <DIV STYLE="margin-left:1em;text-indent:-2em">
        <SPAN class="b">
          <xsl:call-template name="entity-ref">
            <xsl:with-param name="name">nbsp</xsl:with-param>
          </xsl:call-template>
        </SPAN>
        <SPAN class="m">&lt;</SPAN>
        <SPAN>
          <xsl:attribute name="class">
            <xsl:if test="xsl:*">
              <xsl:text>x</xsl:text>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:text>t</xsl:text>
          </xsl:attribute>
          <xsl:value-of select="name(.)"/>
          <xsl:if test="@*">
            <xsl:text>&#160;</xsl:text>
          </xsl:if>
        </SPAN>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
        <SPAN class="m">
          <xsl:text>/></xsl:text>
        </SPAN>
      </DIV>
    </DIV>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*[node()]">
    <DIV class="e">
      <DIV class="c">
        <A class="b" href="#" onclick="return false" onfocus="h()">-</A>
        <SPAN class="m">&lt;</SPAN>
        <SPAN>
          <xsl:attribute name="class">
            <xsl:if test="xsl:*">
              <xsl:text>x</xsl:text>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:text>t</xsl:text>
          </xsl:attribute>
          <xsl:value-of select="name(.)"/>
          <xsl:if test="@*">
            <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
          </xsl:if>
        </SPAN>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
        <SPAN class="m">
          <xsl:text>></xsl:text>
        </SPAN>
      </DIV>
      <DIV>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
        <DIV>
          <SPAN class="b">
            <xsl:call-template name="entity-ref">
              <xsl:with-param name="name">nbsp</xsl:with-param>
            </xsl:call-template>
          </SPAN>
          <SPAN class="m">
            <xsl:text>&lt;/</xsl:text>
          </SPAN>
          <SPAN>
            <xsl:attribute name="class">
              <xsl:if test="xsl:*">
                <xsl:text>x</xsl:text>
              </xsl:if>
              <xsl:text>t</xsl:text>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:value-of select="name(.)"/>
          </SPAN>
          <SPAN class="m">
            <xsl:text>></xsl:text>
          </SPAN>
        </DIV>
      </DIV>
    </DIV>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*[text() and not (comment() or processing-instruction())]">
    <DIV class="e">
      <DIV STYLE="margin-left:1em;text-indent:-2em">
        <SPAN class="b">
          <xsl:call-template name="entity-ref">
            <xsl:with-param name="name">nbsp</xsl:with-param>
          </xsl:call-template>
        </SPAN>
        <SPAN class="m">
          <xsl:text>&lt;</xsl:text>
        </SPAN>
        <SPAN>
          <xsl:attribute name="class">
            <xsl:if test="xsl:*">
              <xsl:text>x</xsl:text>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:text>t</xsl:text>
          </xsl:attribute>
          <xsl:value-of select="name(.)"/>
          <xsl:if test="@*">
            <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
          </xsl:if>
        </SPAN>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
        <SPAN class="m">
          <xsl:text>></xsl:text>
        </SPAN>
        <SPAN class="tx">
          <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </SPAN>
        <SPAN class="m">&lt;/</SPAN>
        <SPAN>
          <xsl:attribute name="class">
            <xsl:if test="xsl:*">
              <xsl:text>x</xsl:text>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:text>t</xsl:text>
          </xsl:attribute>
          <xsl:value-of select="name(.)"/>
        </SPAN>
        <SPAN class="m">
          <xsl:text>></xsl:text>
        </SPAN>
      </DIV>
    </DIV>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*[*]" priority="20">
    <DIV class="e">
      <DIV STYLE="margin-left:1em;text-indent:-2em" class="c">
        <A class="b" href="#" onclick="return false" onfocus="h()">-</A>
        <SPAN class="m">&lt;</SPAN>
        <SPAN>
          <xsl:attribute name="class">
            <xsl:if test="xsl:*">
              <xsl:text>x</xsl:text>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:text>t</xsl:text>
          </xsl:attribute>
          <xsl:value-of select="name(.)"/>
          <xsl:if test="@*">
            <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
          </xsl:if>
        </SPAN>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
        <SPAN class="m">
          <xsl:text>></xsl:text>
        </SPAN>
      </DIV>
      <DIV>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
        <DIV>
          <SPAN class="b">
            <xsl:call-template name="entity-ref">
              <xsl:with-param name="name">nbsp</xsl:with-param>
            </xsl:call-template>
          </SPAN>
          <SPAN class="m">
            <xsl:text>&lt;/</xsl:text>
          </SPAN>
          <SPAN>
            <xsl:attribute name="class">
              <xsl:if test="xsl:*">
                <xsl:text>x</xsl:text>
              </xsl:if>
              <xsl:text>t</xsl:text>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:value-of select="name(.)"/>
          </SPAN>
          <SPAN class="m">
            <xsl:text>></xsl:text>
          </SPAN>
        </DIV>
      </DIV>
    </DIV>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="entity-ref">
    <xsl:param name="name"/>
    <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&amp;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="$name"/>
    <xsl:text>;</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Consider to post a link to a minimal but complete example that works with IE but not with Chrome, explaining exactly in what way it "does not work". Do you get any errors in the browser console? As for Mozilla Firefox, see whether https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XSL_Transformations_in_Mozilla_FAQ gives you any clue why something does not work. If that does not help, I would also like to see a link to a minimal but complete sample working in IE but not at all with Firefox.

Comment: Thanks for reply @MartinHonnen . I included my code and xsl content which works in IE, Chrome but not in Firefox. May be you will get where i'm mistaken

Comment: Just a side note: why are you not doing the transformation serverside? Then you could use compiled xslt and simplify your js client code a lot, for example with knockout.js, jquery or other convenience libs.

Comment: There are various issues with your posted code sample, mostly related to Javascript however, not to XSLT. In terms of XSLT, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XSL_Transformations_in_Mozilla_FAQ#Can_I_do_disable-output-escaping.3F, the use of `disable-output-escaping` does not work with Mozilla.

Comment: As for the script code, both the one you posted to run the XSLT as well as the one you have inside of the HTML generated with XSLT, I see various problems like use of `innerText` or `children(0)` which are not supported in Mozilla and should be replaced with W3C DOM like `textContent` respectively `children[0]` for instance.

Comment: Also what happens in your code after `var output = transformXML(loadedXml, loadedXSL, null);`, where do you use the `output`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using client side XSLT transformations in the HTML5 era](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9847395/using-client-side-xslt-transformations-in-the-html5-era)